# How to resize webpart content (Excel sheet) without scrollbars in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, data-view-web-part

I have a business data-excel web access web part. I need help for below issue.
How to resize webpart content (Excel sheet) without scrollbars in SharePoint 2013?
Please assist.

Comment: By using JavaScript to recalculate the width and height (and set the CSS with and height) until it fills the DIV without scrollbars

Comment: Hi Danny.. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @DannyEngelman : Can you please guide me?

Comment: From this and other replies I gather you are new to SharePoint. Start with learning the basics, Workflows, simple JavaScript and CSS changes. Then you continue with this more complex adaptations. I am sorry, but I can not coach you in a Formula-1 race if you have never driven a car/cart. Start with http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this problem to add new site for this type of excel sheets and use it wide layout (change masterpage) for it which will be accurate for excel sheets

Comment: A whole new SiteCollection? That is like saying, **my drawer is full, lets built a new building**. What about some [simple CSS to hide the QuickLaunch](http://www.onlysharepoint2013.com/2015/01/remove-sharepoint-2013-quick-launch-bar.html) OR use a different Page Template for displaying Excel files OR apply that wide Masterpage to just one site with Excel files,

Comment: This what I was trying to say it

Answer (score 0):

There is an out of the box setting in webpart properties. You can increase the width to your required limit and the excel will render. This of course will have scroll bar if your excel is bigger than the page itself in terms of height.

This property increases the height of the webpart but does not re size the tables and cells.